# Password generator on Android

Tags: java, android

I've just begun creating android applications, and the first idea was like "create random password generator for android just for practice".

I did, but it was like [this](https://s12.postimg.org/voo1nol8t/Screenshot_1026_12_04_13_05_46.png).

Here comes the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ru.hashmap.myapplol.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Your password should be here"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="generate!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="genPass"/>

    <SeekBar
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="15"
        android:progress="6"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and code here:

```
package ru.hashmap.myapplol;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void genPass(View view)
    {
        SeekBar seek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        int seekValue = seek.getProgress()+1;
        Log.d("seekValue", seekValue+"");
        String[] dict = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");
        String[] pass = new String[seekValue];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < seekValue; i++) {
            pass[i] = dict[rnd.nextInt(dict.toString().length())];
        }
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText(pass.toString());
        Log.d("pass", pass+"");
    }
}
```

How to make it work as expected?

Comment: print your stacktrace/log or your output

Comment: first of all you do not seem to call the genPass method anywhere. Why do you have both progress bar and seekbar?

Comment: @helldawg13 `ProgressBar` is just like html `<hr>` tag, im too lazy to search any other paths. `genPass` is called from the `android:onClick` method

Comment: so if i understand correctly you want to generate random passwords using a seekbar to justify the length of that?

Answer (score 3):

There is simply no issue , you are just printing the reference address of an array here `setText(pass.toString())` which will look like something  `[Ljava.lang.String;@52e922`

You need a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` to append the chars and later display it as a string .

```
        SeekBar seek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        int seekValue = seek.getProgress()+1;
        Log.d("seekValue", seekValue+"");
        String[] dict = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");
        Random rnd = new Random();
        StringBuilder str= new StringBuilder();
        for(int k = 0; k < seekValue; k++) {
            str.append(dict[rnd.nextInt(dict.length)]);
        }
        // don't use this , will display reference of array
       //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText(pass.toString()); 

       ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText(str.toString());
       // use this and avoid array in this case
```

dict.toString again give you the reference address who's length will not be similar to `[Ljava.lang.String;@52e922` mean this `dict.toString().length()` always give length around 26 so your password will include char always around this limit so to get actual length of your `dict` array i.e 62, use  `dict.length`

Comment: but then password doesn't have uppercase and part of lowercase letters

Comment: @HashMap it's the same issue try updated answer and implement it , problem will be resolved surely

Comment: still same, and `str` length is sometimes not equal to the `seekValue`

Comment: @HashMap can give an example what exactly you mean by above , let seek bar value is 10 and password length is 10 so what exactly is not happening according to you , give example

Comment: @HashMap seems like there suppose to be no issue about password length , please clarify your particular case and issue ,just make sure you are using the same code i posted

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `pass` as an array, but try to use it in scalar context:

```
String[] pass = new String[seekValue];
...
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText(pass.toString());
```

In this case `toString()` will **dump** the array, including elements type and start memory address.

You need to address a single element of this array, like

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText(pass[i].toString());
```

But I can't guess how to determine the correct index value.